# When JavaFX tab should be collected by garbage collector?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, javafx

I have `TabPane` with `Tab`s in it. I'm creating new `Tab`, adding it to my `TabPane`.
Then I close the tab and remove it from `TabPane` programmatically.

`Tab` is not set to `null`. Is it correct behavior? How to clean / destruct this `Tab` object?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: It's simple code, I've just added event handler that is removing tab from TabPane via setOnClosed(event); method. Nothing special. I'm just  wondering if this is correct behavior.

Comment: Correct behaviour of what?  Your code?  The JavaFX classes?  The garbage collector?  What makes you *think* that something is not correct?  What is happening?

Comment: I would like to know if Java/JavaFx should clean / destruct Tab right after it is closed and / or removed from TabPane, that is it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The garbage collector doesn't destroy objects that you are still holding a reference to.

Assuming you have a local variable or a field `myTab`, then simply assign

```
myTab = null;
```

afterwards to let the garbage collector do his job. If you have other references to this object instance, do the same for them.

Comment: i have 1000 Class in side one tab , then Tab is null but this 1000 Class is not clear .. please help me ...

Answer (score 0):

Your Tab might still have an EventHandler holding the reference.

```
tab.setOnClosed(null);
```

Example:

```
// I make setOnClose handler in my constructor
// My set on close handler will close my project
tab.setOnClosed(new EventHandler<Event>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Event t) {
        closeProject();
    }
});

// Somehow my setOnClose handler still exists after closing the tab

public void closeProject() {

// Setting the setOnClose handler to null fixes the garbage collection issue for me
tab.setOnClosed(null);

tab.setUserData(null);
tab = null;
}
```